# Error rule not getting triggered during MQ error

Tags: xslt, xslt-1.0, xslt-2.0, ibm-mq, ibm-datapower

Am trying to use unit of work by setting the backout value(2) and count .

I can see in the response log as below

source-mq (FSH_POC_CorrelationID): Could not open, destination queue or topic object is unknown (Reason Code 2085)

but still the error rule is not getting triggered , instead its going through the response rule and putting the message on to backout queue.
Tried changing the Process backend errors to OFF , but still the same.

Thanks & Regards,
Sreevathsa A
9986186302

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are using dynamic backend for MQ, you need to use skip-backside action in the request rule .

In XSLT you need to put choose condition ,if it is success copy the data else dp:reject. In else condition ,if you reject it will trigger error rule.

Comment: Hi Jyo,

I don't think the above mentioned answer matches my question.
My Question is , I have a http backed and to test the failure scenario , we have deleted the PUT Queue(queue on to which the response from http will be sent to ... configured in MQFSH) so that the transaction fails with 2085 error .
Failure is happening and can see the error in logs but this failure is not triggering the error rule and showing response rule as success.

Comment: HTTP response you are storing in a PUT queue. You deleted PUT queue and you are testing. Am I correct?

Comment: Yes...
But still the error rule is not getting triggered

Comment: I think it will not trigger becuase you are declaring queue in MQ FSH ,you can see in logs. If you are using dynamic queue , you can trigger rule as mentione above. You can make MQ fsh down and check the scenario it may trigger error rule.

Comment: Thts fine.
How can I achieve it my scenario ?